# Why I cannot find files easily in windows without fully knowing close to the full name of a file?

Tags: windows-10, search, search-indexing

I search for report

This is what I got

[image]

I asked for Report

Again

[image]

[image]

Now if I search for gridtradingreport, tada I found the file but that is kind of silly.

[image]

It may be related to rebuilding index never finish. Clicking rebuild don't finish it either

[image]

And my friend can search fine

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is what it is.  However, it's not a problem for me, I organise my files in the first place.

You could try another tool.   I don't use it but colleagues swear by [Everything](https://everything.en.softonic.com/)  It may improve your experience.

> **A free search tool for Windows**
> Everything is a system utility software that can help you find any file or folder stored on your Windows device. It works blazingly fast and provides users with results in real-time. While the Everything search app doesn’t do anything other than search for data, it does this efficiently and without using too many system resources.
>
> The latest version of the Everything app for Windows works with 32 and 64-bit versions and is easy to set up and use. It offers several search-focussed features that help find documents, images, videos, and audio files quite easily. Users can even customize the software based on individual preferences. A few alternatives that also offer similar functions as the Everything app are Ava Find, SearchMyFiles, and Windows Search.
> ..
>
> **What are the features of the Everything app?**
>
> One of the most prominent features of the Everyday app for Windows is that it lets users search **data via keywords**. This makes searching for files a lot easier, as you don’t have to particularly remember the name of the document you wish to find. While you can’t write long sentences in the search bar, entering a few phrases will give results.

I am not associated with it in any way.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite liely that the index is the problem. Sucessful indexing is clearly why your friend can find the files -- note that `Report` is found in the *content* of the file, not the filename.

Your search is not finding your files because (seemingly) the content is not indexed.

Your search doesn't find your file based on name becasue search is word-based, not character-based, and the `R` in the file name is not preceded by a character recognized as a word seperator.

While you search for troubleshooting indexing issues, you should be able to find your file by name if you add a wildcard at the beginning of the query. Either:

- `*report`

or, more specifically:

- `name:*report`

---

### Edit: More on indexing...

My indexing options look like this:

[image]

But you are trying to index your entire `C:\` drive! It's probably running into issues with permissions on various system folders. You should narrow that down. Have you compared your indexed locations with your friend's?